# Unweighted shortest path

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, data-structures

How do I find the shortest unweighted path that has the shortest weighted path...eg if I have two unwighted path A->B->C =2 and A->D->F =2....how do I print the one with less weighted path?

The code for the unweighted and weighted path are Like this:

```
public void unweighted( String startName )
{
    clearAll( ); 

    Vertex start = vertexMap.get( startName );
    if( start == null )
        throw new NoSuchElementException( "Start vertex not found" );

    Queue<Vertex> q = new LinkedList<Vertex>( );
    q.add( start ); start.dist = 0;

    while( !q.isEmpty( ) )
    {
        Vertex v = q.remove( );

        for( Edge e : v.adj )
        {
            Vertex w = e.dest;
            if( w.dist == INFINITY )
            {
                w.dist = v.dist + 1;
                w.prev = v;
                q.add( w );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

weighted:

```
public void dijkstra( String startName )
{
    PriorityQueue<Path> pq = new PriorityQueue<Path>( );

    Vertex start = vertexMap.get( startName );
    if( start == null )
        throw new NoSuchElementException( "Start vertex not found" );

    clearAll( );
    pq.add( new Path( start, 0 ) ); start.dist = 0;

    int nodesSeen = 0;
    while( !pq.isEmpty( ) && nodesSeen < vertexMap.size( ) )
    {
        Path vrec = pq.remove( );
        Vertex v = vrec.dest;
        if( v.scratch != 0 )  // already processed v
            continue;

        v.scratch = 1;
        nodesSeen++;

        for( Edge e : v.adj )
        {
            Vertex w = e.dest;
            double cvw = e.cost;

            if( cvw < 0 )
                throw new GraphException( "Graph has negative edges" );

            if( w.dist > v.dist + cvw )
            {
                w.dist = v.dist +cvw;
                w.prev = v;
                pq.add( new Path( w, w.dist ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I want to print unweighted path with less weighted path,Please help.

Comment: Huh? What does shortest unweighted path that has the shortest weighted path mean?

Comment: An unweighted path is the same as a weighted path where all the weights are the same. e.g. 1.  If any part of the path is weighted, it the weights are no longer the same.

Answer (score 1):

OK I'm going to take a rough stab at this... Loop through your list of unweighted paths.  For each one, navigate through the path structure, adding up all of the weights.  Grab the one with the smallest value.  Your code will look something like this, using a typical find maximum / minimum pattern:

```
int minimum = 99999;  // use a value obviously larger than all paths
PathClass minPath = null;

for (PathClass path : unweightedPaths) {
    int total = 0;

    for (PathItemClass item : path) {
        total += item.weight;
    }

    if (total < minimum) {
        minimum = total;
        minPath = path;
    }
}

// do something with path, which is the smallest weighted path
```

Please let me know if I'm at all on the right track??